# What type of Join Syntax is this?

Tags: sql, vertica

So I've never seen a join syntax like this before, and I am curious at what it is called and what the use case is for it?

It seems to preforms similar to when you join to a subquery, without actually creating a subquery.

```
from member ddm
inner join trace_execution ssn on ddm.id = ssn.id 
**left join dw_member_subscription dms 
  inner join dw_d_subscription dds on dms.id = dds.id 
  on ddm.id = dms.id**
```

Comment: It looks like a `JOIN` Syntax error. The `LEFT JOIN` has no `ON` clause and the `INNER JOIN` has two.

Comment: That is what I thought as well, but the SQL statement runs fine. I've just never seen anything formatted like that before. (The end results is basically as if the ** ** portion is wrapped up as a subquery) I'm thinking it might possible be a simplified syntax for subqueries native to Vertica, but again not really sure.

Comment: The only logical way for it to be interpreted is `from member ddm
inner join trace_execution ssn on ddm.id = ssn.id 
left join (dw_member_subscription dms 
  inner join dw_d_subscription dds on dms.id = dds.id)
  on ddm.id = dms.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN`s can be nested like this.  It is interpreted as:

```
from member ddm inner join
     trace_execution ssn
     on ddm.id = ssn.id left join
     (dw_member_subscription dms inner join
      dw_d_subscription dds
      on dms.id = dds.id 
     )
     on ddm.id = dms.id
```

I wouldn't write SQL like this in general.  However, I wish the standard required parentheses to make it clear what is going on when the `JOIN`s are not interleaved with their corresponding `ON` clauses.

Comment: That makes perfect sense - Yeah it definitely is a bit jarring not having the delineation of a parenthesis in the SQL itself.